# React Nextjs - module import using @ no longer working

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I was able to import modules using @ but I upgraded a few components including react and nextjs.

this used to work

```
import { ValidateProps } from '@/api-lib/constants';
```

Now getting error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/api-lib/constants'
```

It works if I give it a path

```
import { ValidateProps } from '../../api-lib/constants';
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use a `jsconfig.json` file. It contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Then I am able to import like so:

`import Loadable from "components/ui/Loadable";`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured I no longer had jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/api-lib/*": ["api-lib/*"],
    }
  }
}
```